# Como centralizar o titulo de um JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Eu tenho um componente jFrame e quero centralizar o titulo dele, seria possível?

[image: Titulo do jFrame]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nativamente não é possível, mas há uma solução que pode resolver de forma alternativa, encontrada nesta [**resposta do SOEn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662974/5524514), que seria alinhando o texto de forma justificada a esquerda:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author diego
 */
public class JFrameTitleCenter {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame t = new JFrame();
        t.setSize(600, 300);
        t.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        Font f = t.getFont();
        FontMetrics fm = t.getFontMetrics(f);
        int x = fm.stringWidth("Hello Center");
        int y = fm.stringWidth(" ");
        int z = t.getWidth() / 2 - (x / 2);
        int w = z / y;
        String pad = "";
        //for (int i=0; i!=w; i++) pad +=" "; 
        pad = String.format("%" + w + "s", pad);
        t.setTitle(pad + "Hello Center");

        t.setVisible(true);
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFrameTitleCenter().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução acima tem uma pequena limitação, que é de não funcionar corretamente em janelas redimensionáveis, para isso, você precisa detectar redimensionamento e reescrever o título após este evento, conforme explicado abaixo.

---

## Update

Desenvolvi uma forma de tornar a centralização conforme o tamanho da tela, ou seja, utilizando o método abaixo, é possível liberar redimensionamento, de forma que o título será ajustado ao novo tamanho da janela:

```
private void titleAlign(JFrame frame) {

    Font font = frame.getFont();
    
    String currentTitle = frame.getTitle().trim();
    FontMetrics fm = frame.getFontMetrics(font);
    int frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
    int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(currentTitle);
    int spaceWidth = fm.stringWidth(" ");
    int centerPos = (frameWidth / 2) - (titleWidth / 2);
    int spaceCount = centerPos / spaceWidth;
    String pad = "";
    // for (int i=0; i!=w; i++) pad +=" ";
    pad = String.format("%" + (spaceCount - 14) + "s", pad);
    frame.setTitle(pad + currentTitle);

}
```

O que fiz foi delegar a um método a parte a centralização do título, passando apenas a referência da tela.

Porém, é preciso fazer com que esse método seja chamado toda vez que a tela for redimensionada, e para isso basta adicionar um `ComponentListener`, sobrescrevendo o método [`componentSized()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized-java.awt.event.ComponentEvent-) da tela em que se pretende centralizar o título:

```
seuJFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        titleAlign(seuJFrame);
    }
});
```

Após isso, a tela passará a ajustar o título de forma automática, após cada redimensionamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A janela não é redimensionável então acredito que a solução deva funcionar, vou testar depois. Obrigado @diegofm